# Launch gnu screen from python?

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess, gnu-screen

I tried executing a server daemon with gnu screen from subprocess call but it didn't even start

```
subprocess.call(["screen", "-dmS test ./server"])
```

I was told that running screen requires terminal, hence the reason why I can't simply execute it with call. Can you show me some piece of codes to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
subprocess.call( ["screen", "-d", "-m", "-S", "test", "./server"] )
```

You need to break the argument string into separate arguments, one per string.

Here's the relevant quote from the `subprocess` docs:

> On UNIX, with shell=False (default): In this case, the Popen class
>    uses os.execvp() to execute the child program.  args should normally
>    be a sequence.  A string will be treated as a sequence with the string
>    as the only item (the program to execute).
>
> On UNIX, with shell=True: If args is a string, it specifies the
>    command string to execute through the shell.  If args is a sequence,
>    the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items
>    will be treated as additional shell arguments.

So by default, the arguments are used exactly as you give them; it doesn't try to parse a string into multiple arguments. If you set `shell` to `true`, you could try the following:

```
subprocess.call("screen -dmS test ./server", shell=True)
```

and the string would be parsed exactly like a command line.

Comment: Thanks! That works but it's strange that I need to break all the args that way. Thought I could put all the arguments together

Comment: Answer updated to (attempt to) explain why breaking up the args is necessary.